# asp.net core 2 Identity custom storage provider with default stores

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a question concerning asp.net core Identity (2.1) and the custom storage provider.

In the doc there is the following (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

> To create a custom storage provider, create the data source, the data access layer, and the store classes that interact with this data access layer (the green and grey boxes in the diagram above). You don't need to customize the managers or your app code that interacts with them (the blue boxes above).

So with a custom implementation of UserStore it's work great, but I was asking myself is there is a way to only create the custom Data Access Layer and keep the Microsoft's implementation of the stores?

I can't find a way to do it, so any help will be welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The stores are essentially the repositories utilized by Identity. In other words, they *are* the data access layer. Your implementations of `IUserStore`, `IRoleStore`, etc. are what give Identity the ability to retrieve stuff from your custom data store.